# highlight listview item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, highlight

I need to highlight a listview item when i touch it and to stay highlighted. I tried everything I found but nothing worked. Here is my code:

This is the listview:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvUsers"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/border2"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:padding="5dp" >
</ListView>
```

The `@drawable/border2` is just a border around the listview.

This is the listview item layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layoutUsersRow"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector_background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAllUsersName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="User name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

This is list_selector_background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/blue" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/blue" /> <!-- focused and pressed-->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/blue" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

This is the code from the listview adapter

```
public class UsersAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

LoginActivity context;
private List<String> listOfUsers;

public UsersAdapter(LoginActivity _context, List<String> listOfUsers) {
    context = _context;
    this.listOfUsers = listOfUsers;
}

public int getCount() {
    return listOfUsers.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listOfUsers.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String entry = listOfUsers.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.users_row, null);
    }

    TextView UserName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvAllUsersName);
    UserName.setText(entry);

    LinearLayout LinLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutUsersRow);
    LinLayout.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    LinLayout.setFocusable(false);
    LinLayout.setOnClickListener(this);

    return convertView;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // get the row the clicked button is in
    LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) v;

    TextView child = (TextView) row.getChildAt(0);
    if (child.getText().toString().equals("Admin")) {
        Intent i = new Intent("com.vorteksed.checkinform.ADMINLOGINACTIVITY");
        i.putExtra("verificationFor", "ADMIN_LOGIN");
        context.startActivity(i);
    } else {
        context.userClicked(child.getText().toString());

        // focus the pin field after selecting user name from the list
        if (context.currentList != null) {
            context.etLoginPin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            context.tvPin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            context.etLoginPin.requestFocus();
            context.etLoginPin.setText("");
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(context.etLoginPin, 0);
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is not working. It only highlights the item while it's pressed. As soon as i release it, the highlight is gone.

**HERE IS THE SOLUTION**

Remove the `android:background="@drawable/list_selector_background"` line from the listview item layout. The selector is not needed at all. And here is the adapter's code:

```
public class UsersAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

LoginActivity context;
private List<String> listOfUsers;
boolean[] arrBgcolor;
private int blue = Color.BLUE;
private int transparent = Color.TRANSPARENT;

public UsersAdapter(LoginActivity _context, List<String> listOfUsers) {
    context = _context;
    this.listOfUsers = listOfUsers;

    arrBgcolor = new boolean[listOfUsers.size()];
    resetArrbg();

}

private void resetArrbg() {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrBgcolor.length; i++) {
        arrBgcolor[i] = false;                  
    }
}

public int getCount() {
    return listOfUsers.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listOfUsers.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String entry = listOfUsers.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.users_row, null);
    }


    TextView UserName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvAllUsersName);
    UserName.setText(entry);

    LinearLayout LinLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutUsersRow);
    LinLayout.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    LinLayout.setFocusable(false);
    LinLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            handleClick(v, position);
        }
    });

    if (arrBgcolor[position])
        LinLayout.setBackgroundColor(blue);
    else 
        LinLayout.setBackgroundColor(transparent);

    return convertView;
}

public void handleClick(View v, int position) {
    LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) v;

    resetArrbg();
    arrBgcolor[position] = true;
    notifyDataSetChanged();

    TextView child = (TextView) row.getChildAt(0);
    if (child.getText().toString().equals("Admin")) {
        Intent i = new Intent("com.vorteksed.checkinform.ADMINLOGINACTIVITY");
        i.putExtra("verificationFor", "ADMIN_LOGIN");
        context.startActivity(i);
    } else {
        context.userClicked(child.getText().toString());

        // focus the pin field after selecting user name from the list
        if (context.currentList != null) {
            context.etLoginPin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            context.tvPin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            context.etLoginPin.requestFocus();
            context.etLoginPin.setText("");
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(context.etLoginPin, 0);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Check out this link. It might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565999/how-to-highlight-selected-item-in-listview?rq=1

Comment: Already seen it. Didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the selector and try the following:

**EDIT**

```
public class UsersAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

        LoginActivity context;
        private List<String> listOfUsers;
        boolean[] arrBgcolor;
        private int blue = Color.BLUE;

        public UsersAdapter(LoginActivity _context, List<String> listOfUsers) {
            context = _context;
            this.listOfUsers = listOfUsers;

            arrBgcolor = new boolean[listOfUsers.size()];
            resetArrbg();

        }

        private void resetArrbg() {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrBgcolor.length; i++) {
                arrBgcolor[i] = false;                  
            }
        }

        ......

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            String entry = listOfUsers.get(position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.users_row, null);
            }


            TextView UserName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvAllUsersName);
            UserName.setText(entry);

            LinearLayout LinLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutUsersRow);
            LinLayout.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            LinLayout.setFocusable(false);
            LinLayout.setOnClickListener(this);

            //add the following, the position is accessible from here
            if (arrBgcolor[position]) {
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(blue);
            }
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    resetArrbg();
                    arrBgcolor[position] = true;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }); 
            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: This gives multiple selection. And also when I scroll the list view, the selection repeats on several items, although I selected only one.

Comment: the selection repeats because you are not handling the convertView background. Using ArrayList solves the problem because you are checking for each position one by one.

Comment: @mango I handled the multiple selection, but what about the repeating selection when scrolling?

Comment: what do you mean? you mean the selection is occurring at different positions? try the above edited code.

Comment: Here's what I'm talking about: If I click the first item it highlights it. But if I scroll down there are a couple more items are highlighted. Why is this happening?

Comment: @Shakti You say that if I use ArrayList instead of boolean list it will solve the repeating problem?

Comment: i am saying to take care of `else` case too. `else` `convertView.setBackgroundColor(transparent)`

Comment: using an arraylist won't do you any better, in fact it'd be worse. are you sure that you're using the exact code above? did you remember `resetArrbg();` in the `convertView.setOnClickListener`. do you have any other bg color code in the other onClick? double-check, this shouldn't be happening.

Comment: @mango Yeas I'm using the exact same code, I copied and paste it over my code. The multiple selection still exists, and there's another problem... my edit text doesn't get focus because now I click the convert view and not the Linear Layout so the onClick for the linear layout doesn't get called. I have to put the both in the Linear Layout click listener.

Comment: Finally solved it! Added the solution to the question for those who need it. Thanks @mango and Shakti for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

////@drawable/list_selector

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal"
  android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_activated="false"/>

  <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_touch"
  android:state_pressed="true"/>

 <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_touch"
 android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>

 <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed"
  android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

////////////////////and on ListView

```
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:divider="#060606"/>
```

///////////////////////listview Item

```
       <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

      <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/icon"
      android:layout_width="35dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
      android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

      </RelativeLayout>
```