# Android CustomListView item higlhight on click

Tags: android, listview, click, highlight

I want to highlight item clicked on custom listview. I tried different options but not of them are working. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

my custom listview `com.foo.ViewEditListView extends ListView implements android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener`

list_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_list_info"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        >
    </TextView>

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/searchQueryText"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="left"
         android:drawableRight="@drawable/search"
         android:hint="Search Expenses by Amount"        
         android:textColorHint="#5e8e19"
         android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
         style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"         
          >

        </EditText>

     <com.foo.ViewEditListView
        android:id="@+id/viewExpenseListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:background="@/drawable/list_selector_bg" //doesn't work
         />

</LinearLayout>

list_row.xml 

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@/drawable/list_selector_bg" //doesn't work
    >

 <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"

     >

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/v_row_field1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#C11B17"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/v_row_field2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp" />

  </RelativeLayout>  

</LinearLayout>



list_selector_bg.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@android:drawable/list_selector_background" />      


</selector>
```

I also tried to setSelector in Activity but none of them are working. Right now, i am clueless. Can someone help me here?

If i put android:background="@/drawable/list_selector_bg" into RelativeLayout, it highlights only that portion. But i want whole layout to be highlighted.

Thanks
CP

Answer (score 1):

Have custom drawable set as background for the layout. Modify the below according to your needs. When pressed you will have different background and on release will return to the default state.

In your list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:background="@drawable/listbkg" // set backcground
android:orientation="vertical"
 >
....
</LinearLayout>
```

listbkg.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" /> //pressed state
<item  android:state_focused="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/normal" /> // normal state
</selector>
```

pressed.xml in drawable fodler

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<solid android:color="#FF1A47"/>     //background color 
<stroke android:width="3dp"          // border color
        android:color="#0FECFF"/>
<padding android:left="5dp"
         android:top="5dp"
         android:right="5dp"
         android:bottom="5dp"/> 
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"  //for rounded corners    
         android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
         android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
         android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

normal.xml in drawable folder

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>    //  change olor
<stroke android:width="3dp"   // for border color
        android:color="#0FECFF" />

<padding android:left="5dp"
         android:top="5dp"
         android:right="5dp"
         android:bottom="5dp"/> 
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"// for rounded corners
         android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
         android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
         android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Edit:

You can also include gradient as you can see the same in the snap shot.

In getView() of custom adapter

```
     convertView =mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent,false);
     // inflating custom layout
```

Then in list_row.xml set the background for the root layout.

Resulting Snap Shot

When pressed it highlights the layout and on release will go back to normal state.

[image]

Comment: Hi Raghunandan, I tried your solution. But it's not working. Still same behaviour. Do you think VieEditListView is causing some problem?

Comment: @Chintan this should work if you are doing it right. I have used the same for listview row's with the custom drawable as  background.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want highlight selected items you can handle it by using your CustomAdapter. But it's not very good way:)

2) I think, the best way is use common Android implementation of Checkable interface for your view (as example):

```
public class CheckableFrameLayout extends FrameLayout implements Checkable {
    private boolean mChecked;

    public CheckableFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CheckableFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        mChecked = checked;
        setBackgroundDrawable(checked ? new ColorDrawable(0xff0000a0) : null);
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }
}
```

OR

3) Use [CheckedTextView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/CheckedTextView.java)

You can found example in [Android Samples](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html) named as ApiDemos (ListView with multichoice).

**UPDATE:**
Don't forget that your `ListView` must have [ChoiceMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getChoiceMode%28%29) != [ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#CHOICE_MODE_NONE)

Put `CheckableFrameLayout` into your package and rewrite your `list_row.xml` like this:

```
<com.foo.CheckableFrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector_bg"
    >

 <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/v_row_field1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#C11B17"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/v_row_field2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp" />

  </RelativeLayout>  
</com.foo.CheckableFrameLayout>
```

If you want get states for your `CheckableFrameLayout` from statelist (be setting it to background), then you need to override your `list_selector_bg.xml`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@android:drawable/list_selector_background" />
</selector>
```

And rewrite `CheckableFrameLayout` for working with it. I have not done it correctly in haste (I don't know why it change highlight correctly only afer second tap). But you can take this code and improve it (maybe using code of [CheckedTextView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/CheckedTextView.java) can help you):

```
public class CheckableFrameLayout extends FrameLayout implements Checkable {
    private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = {
        android.R.attr.state_checked
    };

    private boolean mChecked;

    public CheckableFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CheckableFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked()) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
        }
        return drawableState;
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        mChecked = checked;
        // setBackgroundDrawable(checked ? new ColorDrawable(0xff0000a0) : null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want checkbox to be displayed. How do i attach CheckableFrameLayout  to my custom listview class (i.e ViewEditListView)?

Comment: I have customAdapter also, how do i implement to highlight selected item?

Comment: @Chintan I'm update my answer. Using adapter it's not very good idea, but a lot of people use it:(
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699818/highlight-listview-item
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137465/highlight-listview-items-android

Comment: Thanks nfirex! I will try your solution too.