# Making a listview item clickable and selectable

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Is it possible to make a listview item both clickable and selectable?

If i set
android:textIsSelectable = "true"

My onitemclicklistener does not work. Or is it possible to highlight the textview in the listview without using textIsSelectable? Cause i used the xml code below to create the highlight in my textview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Selected --> 
  <item 
    android:state_focused="true" 
    android:state_selected="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/focused"/> 
    <item android:drawable="@color/black" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565999/how-to-highlight-selected-item-in-listview

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to do a custom listview.

```
<ScollView><Linearlayout android:id="@+id/listview">  the as a listview of rootView</LinearLayout></ScollView>
```

LinearLayout listView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.listview);
add sub item view into the listView.
so now you can add selector and clicklistener on the sub item view.

Answer (score 0):

it is my wertherApp code:

```
public class MainListAdapter extends BaseAdapter :

   public void change(ArrayList<MainListInfo> mainWether) {

    if (mainWether == null)

        this.mainWether = new ArrayList<MainListInfo>();

    else

        this.mainWether = mainWether;

    this.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

    public void setcurtentitem(int curentitem) {

    this.curentitem = curentitem;

    this.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

 public class MainListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  ……
  if (position == curentitem) {

        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_01_down);

    } else {

        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_01_up);

    }

 ……


 }
```

then in the activity:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            adapter.setcurtentitem(arg2);

        }

    });
```